# jQuery Hover event, prevent function from being fully executed

Tags: jquery, hover

First things first, i find this one a little difficult to explain, as english is not my native language. So excuse the mess.

I wrote a little notification function, which is triggered on form submit. Normal behaviour is:

- User submits form
- Note fades in
- 2 second delay
- Note fades out

When the note is hovered, it expands by `css-transition`. Logically, it should not fade out until the user collapses it by `mouseleave`.
And here lies my problem: How do i prevent the `fadeOut` Statement from being executed, as long as the div is hovered?

I tried something like

```
if ($('#notification').hover()){
    return ;
}
```

but of course, the first statement is already excuted as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6DsJb/

I also tried a few other things, like a seperate script which is listening on the `hover` event, then calling `$('#notification').show() ;`

Neither works. I know this is a simple error in reasoning, but hell, i am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `fadeIn` call `setTimeout`, with a function that:

- If the notifications is collapsed, hide it.
- Else, use `.mouseleave` to hide it once it looses mouse focus.

ie:

```
$('#notification').fadeIn(500);

setTimeout(function() {
  if (notification_is_collapsed)
    $('#notification').fadeOut(500);
  else
    $('#notification').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#notification').fadeOut(500);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Excuse me, but i do not understand this. Does the is_collapsed not mean that the note already disappeared, and, if not, wouldn't it be the same as the mouseleave action?

Comment: `notification_is_collapsed` should be replaced by something that evaluates whether the note have already been collapsed before the 2seconds elapsed.

Comment: Thanks again, i got it, although a little different:

http://pastebin.com/6gpJTgKc

Answer (score 1):

Hover function takes 2 parameters : when the mouse get in, and when the mouse goes out ( http://api.jquery.com/hover/ )

so you can do something like this instead :

```
$('#notification').hover(
function() {}, function() {
    $(this).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
});
```

here is your jsfiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/6DsJb/1/

Comment: Thanks, but this only works without the autofade, so the user explicitly has to hover the note to get rid of it. I tried this in conjunction with the delay autofade, but it still overrides it.